# How to mock an object file containing utility functions in scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking

I am new to testing frameworks, have very little idea about testing but I want to write a unit test case for the scenario here.

As far I got to know that a trait should be built on top of it and let this utility extend that trait but after that I am finding it little difficult to proceed.

```
object utility{
    def abc(a: String, b: Int ): String={}
    def bcd(): Int = {}
}
```

I am using flatspec and MockFactory

`scala 2.11` and `sbt` with following dependencies

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalamock" %% "scalamock" % "4.1.0" % "test",
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.4" % "test"
```

Your help will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well usually you would do sth. like this:

```
trait Utility {
  def abc(a: String, b: Int ): String
  def bcd(): Int
}

object RealUtil extends Utility {
  def abc(a: String, b: Int ): String= ??? //real implementation
  def bcd(): Int = ???
}

class UsesUtil(util: Utility) {
   def doSth(): Int = util.bcd()
}

// allows prod usage like this UsesUtil().doSth
object UsesUtil {
  def apply(util: Utility = RealUtil): UsesUtil = new UsesUtil(util)
}

class HereAreTests {
  // use in tests
  val mockedUtility = new Utility {
    def abc(a: String, b: Int ): String= "mock"
    def bcd(): Int = 42
  }

  // test here
  val useUtilClass = new UsesUtil(mockedUtility)
  val resultFromMock = useUtilClass.doSth()
  assert(resultFromMock == 42)
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks.!! One more thing can you please show a small snippet of how to call this inside a test case..!!

Comment: How to call what exactly in a test? How to use the `UsesUtil` class?
That would be `new UsesUtil(mockedUtility).whateverItCanDo`.

Comment: Object RealUtil contain functions which are mocked for now by creating trait. Now if any class functions need to be tested where we need to invoke these mocked function then how to achieve this..!!

    class A
    {
    def runday : String = {
    abc() --- calling the util function for which we have created mocked 
    object
    }
    }

I basically want to write a unit test case for this function runday() and for that I think it may need me a mocked util function.

Comment: I added some example for how you could use it in a real test. Does that help you? Otherwise not sure if I 100% understood your follow up question.

Comment: Hey Thanks, Many thanks :)
I am incorporating this trick in my code..!!
In case if somewhere I get stuck, I would ask you for some suggestion, Thanks in advance Sir..!!

Comment: sure, you are welcome, you can mark it as the correct answer if you are using it now

Comment: Surely will do it..!!
Now suppose if we want to get mocked output(42) when there is a call for regular function(bcd) from some Another class which we want to test(i.e class square)


Class square
{
main(def Array[String]): Unit = {
def calculate_something()
}

def calculate_something(): String = {

Call to bcd() <==== here if we want to get mocked output (i.e 42)

}
}

While testing the function calculate_something() in test class (i.e HereAreTests)

It would be really great help, as if somehow I clear this hurdle I could possibly develop all test cases for my project

Comment: If you feel its worth answering, can you please like my question so that I can get my points and that enables me to mark your answer.. Actually I am falling short of 4 points here to mark the your response..!!

Comment: You also would need to inject like with `class UsesUtil(util: Utility)` but look at the `object UsesUtil` I added, this makes it easier to use it in production code with the real `Utility`

Comment: Thanks I will try it

Comment: Hello,
Didn't get your solution or I am unable to fit it in my brain..!!
Can you please elaborate it further more or can you help me with the code the same way as above

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to rincewind's suggestion is to use Mockito:

```
"org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.9.0" % "test"
```

---

```
trait Utility {
  def abc(a: String, b: Int ): String={}
  def bcd(): Int = {}
}

object RealUtil extends Utility {
  def abc(a: String, b: Int ): String= ??? //real implementation
  def bcd(): Int = ???
}

class UsesUtil(util: Utility) {
   // do sth with util
}

class HereAreTests extends MockitoSugar {
  // use in tests
  val mockedUtility = mock[Utility]
  "this" should "do something" in {
    when(mockedUtility.abc(
      ArgumentMatchers.eq("some input string"),
      ArgumentMatchers.anyInt()
    )).thenReturn("my string")
  // tests which call the `abc` function with input of "some input string" and any number
  }
}
```

I find this a lot more helpful when I want to be more specific with my inputs. It means that you can mock out specific expected inputs and outputs and stops you having to re-declare the `val` every time you want to test something different.

That's just personal preference though, I guess :)